# Hot module reload with browserify, redux and react-route

Tags: redux, browserify, hot-module-replacement

I prefer browserify over webpack but there's a problem in browserify environment I can't fix. I'm using react, redux and react-route and I'm willing to have hot module reload like what react-hot-loader offers to webpack environment. I'm using livereactload to achieve this (tried browserify-hmr too) the problem is it doesn't work with redux. Its redux example (https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload/blob/master/examples/02-redux) does not work on a fresh clone. Is it possible at all? Can someone give me changes needed to apply to the example to make it work?

P.S. look at this issue https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload/issues/64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem with `redux` was that I wasn't using `react-proxy@1.x` nor `babel-plugin-react-transform` so my components were not wrapped in proxies.
New versions of livereactload will raise an error if you use it without `react-proxy` or `babel-plugin-react-transform` look at this: https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload/issues/64#issuecomment-231992217

My problem with `react-route` was that I was using a component defined as an arrow function in a Route directive. Apparently `livereactload` doesn't support that. It got solved by using a class component instead of arrow-function. Explanation here: https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload/issues/43#issuecomment-231990841

Answer (score 2):

I am using it but as a watchify plugin: plugin(require('livereactload')) and it works okayish.

I do have LiveReactload :: Bundle changed and page is updated but also this warning: browser.js:51 Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be ignored.

Still it does "local" reload but its not a "true" hot reloading since lots of stuff is still re-rendered and do not achieve as much as I would like.

The only thing we needed to add to configure store is the following:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);

  // React hot reload
  if (module.onReload) {
    module.onReload(() => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer.default || nextReducer);
      // return true to indicate that this module is accepted and
      // there is no need to reload its parent modules
      return true;
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for information. I solved the problem as I described in my answer.